# Stylesheet applied to Javascript via WKWebView works on simulator, fails on device

Tags: javascript, ios, css, swift, wkwebview

With the following setup, I can run my app on a simulator and the stylesheet is properly applied to the content. However, running the exact same code on a device results in the stylesheet being ignored.

How I set up my `WKWebView`:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
let userScript =  WKUserScript(source: "my script goes here",
                                injectionTime: .atDocumentStart,
                                forMainFrameOnly: false)
contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController = contentController
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
// Finish setting up & running web view here
```

For the above section, changing the `injectionTime` to `.atDocumentEnd` and the `forMainFrameOnly` to `true` has no effect.

And a simplified index.html file, which is pretty empty:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Style This Page</title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <body onload="runScript()">
        <div id="scriptAttachesHere"></div>
        <script>
        let script
        window.onload = function() {
            let options = { }
            script = new window.SCRIPT.Name(document.getElementById('scriptAttachesHere'), options);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a snippet of code from the stylesheet:

```
.script-container .devices .contentContainer::before { height: unset !important; }
```

All names have been masked, so the possibility that I did so incorrectly is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be fairly straight forward.

Apple frowns upon loading local files into a `WKWebView`, so I resolved this by merging my stylesheet directly into my HTML code, versus an independent style sheet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Style This Page</title>
    </head>
    <style>
       .script-container .devices .contentContainer::before { height: unset !important; }
    </style>
    <body onload="runScript()">
        <div id="scriptAttachesHere"></div>
        <script>
        let script
        window.onload = function() {
            let options = { }
            script = new window.SCRIPT.Name(document.getElementById('scriptAttachesHere'), options);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the removal of the code for linking to a local stylesheet.